# Target command for date not working on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8

I'm setting up a sound recorder to run at startup. I created a shortcut in the `...Roaming/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Start-up` directory and used this *Target*:

```
C:\Windows\System32\SoundRecorder.exe /FILE C:\Users\Paul\Desktop\output_%date%_%random%.wma /DURATION 0:1:0
```

The output is created but with the exact characters in the path.

**How could I get the current date and random value in the output file name?**